# Is it possible to determine the calling context (function, symbol) in a Common Lisp function?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

There are probably several ways to implement this introspection feature through macros and code walkers, but is there a simpler (possible, implementation-dependent) way? I'd imagine, invoking and then releasing the debugger could open access to frame stack, but that seems like an overkill too.

What would be some simpler ideas to try?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Research? This one's not for an actual application.

Comment: Try [trivial-backtrace](http://www.cliki.net/trivial-backtrace).

Comment: Most implementations have a debugger which can display the call stack. Thus there needs to be an implementation specific function to get the call stack information. Note that the call stack does not show the complete information. Calls could have been eliminated (TCO), code could have been inlined, macros could have been expanded, ...

Comment: There is also `uiop:print-backtrace`.  Uiop comes with ASDF, which comes with many Lisp implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Macros can take an &env argument that passes in the lexical environment of the calling context. You can then query the lexical environment using these functions: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node102.html

In particular, check out `variable-information` and `function-information`.

I believe there are also implementation-specific ways to get the current lexical environment at run-time.